# How to get the 'type name' of an derived entity within LINQ statement : "does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()"

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, inheritance

I wonder if it is possible to get the type of entities that inherits from the same base entity. When I use the following

```
   var db.BaseClass.Select(a => new { Type = a.GetType().Name });
```

I got `"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()' method"` error. I need to know the class name of the entity that inherited from the base class. I know I can use this:

```
  var derivedClass1Items = db.BaseClass.OfType<DerivedClass1>().Select(a => new { Type = "DerivedClass1" });
   var derivedClass2Items = db.BaseClass.OfType<DerivedClass2>().Select(a => new { Type = "DerivedClass2" });
```

However, this looks cumbersome. Is there a way to do this with the first approach, using the `BaseClass` with a single LINQ statement?

**UPDATE**

Here is my real classes:

`Like` : LikeId, LikeDate, WhoLiked, WhoseLiked *base class

`PostLike`: PostId *inherited class

`CommentLike`: CommentId *inherited class

`ReplyLike`: ReplyId *inherited class

Comment: Why are you wanting to select a list of Types in the first place? There doesn't seem to be a practical reason to do this? All you're going to end up with is a list of types with no meaningful data to tie it back to an entity, this seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @AllMadHare of course I have some other properties but did not include them here since they are not related to the actual problem.

Comment: At the end of the day the LINQ query has to be converted to a SQL query.  LINQ to entities does not know how to convert `GetType()` to a SQL function (there is no equivalent SQL function).  You have to execute the query first and do the projection with the resulting objects in memory: `db.BaseClass.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new { Type = x.GetType().Name })`.  I am curious to know how `BaseClass` is defined, though.  Did you use EF code first to create it?

Comment: @JasonBoyd yes it is EF code first I added my classes.

Comment: Okay, I am still trying to wrap my head around how that works in practice.  It seems to me that `db.BaseClass` is always going return the base class objects.  I don't think it would ever return a more derived type.

Comment: @JasonBoyd I decided to share my design as another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837076/dilemma-on-the-use-of-inheritance-in-ef-code-first

Comment: @erkaner Thanks for the clarification, it makes a bit more sense now. I have posted a comment on your new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your best solution

```
var db.Likes.Select(a => new 
    {
        Type = a.PostLike != null 
                ? "PostLike" 
                : a.CommentLike !=null 
                    ? "CommentLike" 
                    : a.ReplyLike != null 
                        ? "ReplyLike"
                        : null
    });
```

but in this way you need to leave the inheritance to use 0:1 navigation properties instead