# dilemma on the use of inheritance in EF code-first

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, inheritance

I am trying to implement `Like` functionality (similar to Facebook) in my application. I will have three types of `Like`s: likes for posts, likes for comments (to the posts), and likes for replies (to the comments). Later, based on the `like` activities I want to generate a dynamic notification list for the user.

For this task, I thought inheritance would work great, so I have the following classes (`Like` is the base class)

`Like` : LikeId, LikeDate, WhoLiked, WhoseLiked, IsNotificationRead

`PostLike`: PostId

`CommentLike`: CommentId

`ReplyLike`: ReplyId

I need to generate a notification list that looks like:

1. User1 liked your post (`PostId` *should be attached to this item*)
2. User2 liked your comment (`CommentId` *should be attached to this)*
   item)
3. User3 liked your reply (`ReplyId` *should be attached to this item)*

However, I am having hard time to generate this output for the last 2 days. Finally, I concluded that I cannot use `dbcontext.Likes` within a single LINQ statement to have this output.

I am planning to generate the list separately for each inherited entity and merge all lists at the end:

```
  var postlikes = db.Like.OfType<PostLike>().Select(a => 
         new {Text = "User1 liked your post", ItemId=a.PostId, Type="Post"});

  var commentlikes = db.Like.OfType<CommentLike>().Select(a => 
         new {Text = "User1 liked your comment", ItemId=a.CommentId, Type="Comment"});

  var replylikes = db.Like.OfType<ReplyLike>().Select(a => 
         new {Text = "User1 liked your reply", ItemId=a.ReplyId, Type="Reply"});
```

Do you think the way I implemented Inheritance makes sense in this scenario? Do you recommend an another approach? Do you think I need inheritance here?

Thanks

Comment: If you're wanting to notify users, it would possibly be better to have a UserNotification object, which could then be independent of the source of the notification(new like, new comment etc), that way you have a nice interface to add new notification types as you add features. This object could contain an instance of an interface (eg INotifiable), which links back to the appropriate object.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have additional members elided from your example, your approach seems overkill. Plus doing 3 queries just to get likes for a notification seems heavy.

A simple implementation would be to have a single `Like` class with `TargetId` and `TargetType` properties, then just adjust the text according the the value of `TargetType`. You wouldn't get navigation properties that way, but you might not need them.

If you wanted your inherited classes like your example, at least refactor so you hit the database only once:

```
var likes = db.Like.ToList();

var postLikes = likes.OfType<CommentLike>()...
```

Comment: You mean, I can just have single `Like` class without navigational properties (`Comment`, `Post`, or `Reply`) but still have the related properties (`TargetId`, `TargetType`) to do what I want to do?

Comment: `TargetId` would just be the value for `PostId`, `CommentId`, or `ReplyId`, and would not be configured as a foreign key. The value of TargetType would tell you the type of object the lIke was for, so you could create a link to the appropriate entry using the id. Hope that makes sense